# AG Chart: Sort bar chart by value

Tags: javascript, ag-charts-react

I created a bar chart with AG Charts:

[image]

As you see, the Y axis is sorted by the category name.
But I want to sort them by the value:

[image]

I checked AG Charts documentation, but couldn't find anything.
Just to clarify, the data it self is sorted by value already.
The problem is that AG Charts automatically resorts it by category name.

### What I already tried

The image above was created by using the values as category name.
I already tried to change the tick labels with a function assigned to `axes[i].label.formatter`.
However, the argument passed to this function do not contain any information about the original data anymore.
It is hard to recreate the categories from this data.
Also, in case two categories have the same value, this solution will omit one category.